# VS2013 - LoadLibrary cannot find dll

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013, loadlibrary

**ISSUE:** dll was compiled to 64-bit, program using dll was being compiled to 32-bit.

**Solution:** compiled the program using the 64-bit dll in 64-bit.

---

I have a dll that I made called `mydll.dll`. I have been able to compile the `.cpp` file outside of VS2013 and was able to load the dll. Once I try to make the same `.cpp` file in VS2013 and `LoadLibrary(mydll.dll)` with the dll in the same folder as my `.cpp` it cannot find the dll, and even if I path directly to the dll it still will not work.

My dll has been shown to work outside of VS2013 so I do not believe that is the source of the problem. The likely source is my ignorance.

Code:

(Main.cpp)

```
int main(void){
    HINSTANCE dllHandle;
    dllHandle = LoadLibrary("mydll.dll");
    if (!dllHandle){
        printf("dll no load\n");
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        printf("dll load!\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not put the dll in the same folder as the cpp file. It should be in the folder that the exe file is in. These will not be the same in Visual Studio by default. Also make sure you are not mixing 32 and 64 bit. I mean you can not load a 32 bit dll in a 64 bit application or a 64 bit dll in a 32 bit application.

Comment: @drescherjm You are very correct! I compiled my Dll with Cuda's NVCC which is 64-bit. All I had to do was change the build settings in VS2013 to x64 and it worked. I will set this as the answer if you post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your dll is in the search paths that windows is using make sure you are not mixing 32 bit and 64 bit. Windows will not load a 32 bit dll into a 64 bit application or a 64 bit dll into a 32 bit application.

**Note**: See the answer by @Nard for how windows searches for dlls: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26435819/487892)

Answer (score 3):

Since the DLL is loaded **when the program runs**, you should either make sure the DLL path supplied to LoadLibrary is relative to the **executable**, or supply an absolute path.  Refer to MSDN documentation on how DLLs are located when you do not provide an absolute path:

[Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx)

The **compiler** will not be the one handling the loading of the DLL in this case so the cpp file does not need to locate the file but instead, the executable will need to locate the file.

Comment: In the question, you only stated that the DLL is located in the same folder as your .cpp, as such I cannot assume that your executable is also run from the same folder.

I've tried your code myself and it works fine for me.

Comment: "and even if I path directly to the dll it still will not work"

Comment: Sorry about that. Shall I remove my answer?